# sorting an array of strings using qsort

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, quicksort

So i have an array of strings called `nova_str[50][1024]` and what i want is to sort it using qsort the problem is that its not sorting anything.

My output:

```
* fcb
* bvb
```

Correct output:

```
* bvb
* fcb
```

as you can see the array isnt being sorted and i cant dont know why, so any help would be appreciated.

Program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int string_cmp (const void * a, const void * b ) {
    const char * pa = *(const char * const * ) a;
    const char * pb = *(const char * const * ) b;

    return strcmp(pa,pb);
}

void print_array(char array[][1024], int len) 
{ 
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        printf("* %s\n",array[i]);
    }

}

int main(void)
{
    char nova_str[50][1024];
    strcpy(nova_str[0],"fcb");
    strcpy(nova_str[1],"bvb");
    qsort(nova_str,1, sizeof(char *)*1024, string_cmp);
    print_array(nova_str,2);
}
```

Comment: There are 2 elements in the array, but you are sorting only 1, it should be something like `qsort(nova_str, 2, sizeof *nova_str, string_cmp);` .

Comment: You sort `1` element only, and you pass the wrong element size as `sizeof(char *)*1024`. That is `1024` time the size of a **pointer**. `qsort(nova_str, 2, sizeof nova_str[0], string_cmp)` would work.

Comment: Also `qsort(nova_str, 2, 1024, strcmp);` will work without making your own comparator function.

Comment: your compare function is wrong, `qsort` (if called correctly as suggested) will pass just the pointer your strings, not a pointer to pointer.

Comment: @WeatherVane using `strcmp` directly will emit a warning of "incompatible pointer type" (at least on `gcc`)

Comment: @MarcoLucidi that seems strange. Does it give a warning for `char*` passed to, for example, `void *memset(void *dest, int c, size_t count);`? Is it because `strcmp` has `const` arguments?

Comment: yes it does give a warning on gcc saying that im passing the wrong type if i use strcmp

Comment: @WeatherVane in the case of `memset` the `char *` in implicitly casted to `void *`. The fourth argument to `qsort` is a function pointer of type `int (*)(const void *, const void *)` and is not compatible with `strcmp` pointer because its type is `int (*)(const char *, const char *)`.

Answer (score 4):

This will work.

```
// You are getting a pointer from qsort, not a pointer to a pointer.
int string_cmp (const void * a, const void * b ) {
    const char * pa = (const char *) a;
    const char * pb = (const char *) b;

    return strcmp(pa,pb);
}

void print_array(char array[][1024], int len) 
{ 
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        printf("* %s\n",array[i]);
    }

}

int main(void)
{
    char nova_str[50][1024];
    strcpy(nova_str[0],"fcb");
    strcpy(nova_str[1],"bvb");
    // the size is 2, not 1
    // you also want the correct size of the elements
    // getting the size of the first element will ensure this
    qsort(nova_str,2, sizeof(nova_str[0]), string_cmp);
    print_array(nova_str,2);
}
```

I hope that this helps.